# injecting $modal into httpProvider

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to inject bootstrap $modal into httpProvider to show internal server error message (500) in modal, but I receive circular dependency error (Circular dependency found: $http <- $modal <- $http <- locale)

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location, $modal) {
    return {
        'response': function (response) {
            return response;
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection, modalInstance) {
            if(rejection.status === 401) {
                console.log('No permissions - redirected to the login page');
                $location.path('/login');
            } else if (rejection.status === 404) {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/modal/error.tpl.html',
                    controller: 'ModalController',
                    size: 'md',
                    resolve: {
                        object: function () {
                            return object;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use $injector:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location, $injector) {
  var modal = $injector.get("$modal");
  modal.open ...
```

Comment: @strongBAD which Angular version do you use? I still get the circular dependency issue.

Comment: Well thats crazy. Me too and I still get circular dependency injection issues when I try to use a modal in a httpinterceptor with $injector.get('$modal')